# Concurrency across a scoped DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous, asp.net-core, concurrency

I have a standard ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web API with a standard DI DbContext as such:

```
services.AdDbContext<TestContext>( ... );
```

I know that my context will be added with a **scoped lifetime** that essentially means that everytime my API gets a new request, it will create a new instance of the context.

So far so good.

Now then, I have created a repository called **TestRepository** that contains the following:

```
public class TestRepository : ITestRepository {
    public TestContext _context;
    public TestRepository(TestContext context) {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task IncrementCounter() {
        var row = await _context.Banks.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        row.Counter += 1;
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

So it basically just increments a value in a column with 1 - *asynchronously*. The ITestRepository is added to services IoC and injected wherever needed.

*Scenario:*

**User A** calls the API, gets a new instance of the TestContext, and now invokes the IncrementCounter method.

**Before** the SaveChangesAsync is called a **User B** has made a call to the API, gotten a new TestContext, and have invoked the IncrementCounter method aswell.

Now **User A** saves the value **1** into the column while **User B** also believes that it should save value **1** but it should actually be **2**.

Even after reading related documentation, I am still unsure how to guarantee, that **IncrementCounter** method are incrementing correctly, even when multiple users are calling the API with their own instance of the **TestContext**.

I might have confused myself more than I should but could someone clarify how concurrency across different instances of the same context are handled?

Related documentation:

- [Concurrency in ASP.NET Core 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/concurrency?view=aspnetcore-2.0)
- [Handling Concurrency Conflicts](https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/ef/core/saving/concurrency)
- [Dependency Injection .NET Core 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.0#entity-framework-contexts)

**Update 1**

I have thought about implementing the [TimeStamp] data-annotation on a new 'rowVersion' property and then catch the DbConcurrencyException, as the related documentation explains, but does that solve the issue that it is a scoped DbContext and therefore different context that are trying to SaveChangesAsync()?

Comment: You should probably use a database transaction to lock the row you are modifying :)

Comment: Yeh that is more or less what my Update 1 describes but I am just confused as to how the framework differs when it is a different context calling.

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using an auto-increment field in your table?

Comment: @DrewB Very good point - I have created a logging feature that counts different statistics. So instead of having a huge amount of rows (which I would need to retrieve via other SQL), I would like to have a counter for each "statistic" e.g. update the column value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This actually doesn't have anything to do with object lifetimes, scoped or otherwise. Concurrency is concurrency. Doing something like incrementing a counter is inherently not thread-safe, so you must either employ locks or optimistic concurrency, just like with any other thread-unsafe task. Database locks are generally frowned upon, so optimistic concurrency is definitely the preferred approach.

How this works on a database-level is that you essentially have a timestamp column, which gets updated with each change. EF is smart enough to watch this column, and if the value it has on update is different than the value it had when you first queried the row, then it aborts the update. At that point, your code catches the exception and handles it by requerying the row and attempting to update it again.

For example, User A and User B attempt to save value 1 at the same time. Let's say User B gets in a few milliseconds earlier and successfully updates the column. This then also updates the timestamp column. When User A's update arrives, the update fails because the timestamp column no longer matches. This bubbles up back to EF, where it throws a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`. Your code catches this exception, and responds by re-querying the row, where the column is now 1, instead of 0 (and gets the latest timestamp), increments to 2, and then attempts to save again. This time, there's no other users doing anything, so it goes through successfully. However, you could also have another concurrency exception. In which case, you need to rinse and repeat, eventually attempting to save 3 to the column, and so on.

You've linked to all the relevant documentation in your question itself, so I suggest you simply take some time to go through all that and really understand it. You'll need to add a new property to the entity where your incremented value is stored:

```
[Timestamp]
public byte[] Version { get; set; }
```

With that (and after you migrate obviously), EF will then begin throwing exceptions on save as described above when there's a conflict. To catch and handle these, I'd suggest using a library like [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly). It lets you set up retry policies, making it trivial to handle this repeated query-increment-save logic.

Comment: Thanks for a thorough answer. And I agree with everything you are saying - I have most likely confused myself with context scoping and the impact it has on concurrency. So my problem is solely on database-level it seems.

Comment: How would I be able to provoke this DBUpdateConcurrencyException? Could I somehow create a small console app that does some Thread.Sleep while second call are made?

Comment: This is not something you do. You merely add the timestamp property to your entity class and migrate the changes to your database. Once the column exists on the table, EF automatically starts employing optimistic concurrency checks. You simply need to be prepared to receive this exception when attempting to save and handle it.

Comment: Let me rephrase. I would like to make a test where I receive the exception in order to understand it properly. This might be out of scope for this question.

Comment: Ah. Well, if you're unit testing, you can simply stub `SaveChanges` to throw the exception. To ensure it eventually succeeds, you would need to employ some feature of your preferred mocking framework that allows you to vary the stub based on the number of calls. Moq, for example, has `Callback` which you can use to only throw the exception on the first time through (via keeping a counter of calls), and otherwise return the appropriate value (which for `SaveChanges` is the number of successful operations).